# How to return additional fields based on aggregate function?

Tags: sql-server-2005, function, aggregate, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables,

**jobcli**

- client_id
- job_id

**jobs**

- job_id
- jobTitle
- startDate
- projectmgr

What I am having trouble with is to display client_id, job_id, jobTitle, startDate, and projectmgr in a query, where the results are grouped by client_id and have max of date.

So far I can get a list that's groupped by client_id with their corresponding max(startDate).

SELECT      client_id, MAX(startDate) AS LastJob
FROM        jobcli INNER JOIN jobs ON jobcli.job_id = dbo.jobs.id
GROUP BY    jobcli.client_id

This query only returns 2 fields, client_id and LastJob, but I also want to display job_id, projectmrg and title for the last job.

This scenario is for a SQL server 2005. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the greatest-n-per-group problem that has come up dozens of times on Stack Overflow.

Here's a couple of solutions:

```
SELECT j1.*
FROM jobcli j1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM jobcli j2 
    WHERE j1.client_id = j2.client_id 
      AND j1.startDate < j2.startDate
);
```

Or since you're using Microsoft SQL Server 2005, you can use windowing functions:

```
WITH rownumbered_jobcli AS (
  SELECT j.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY j.client_id 
                                 ORDER BY j.startDate DESC) AS RN
  FROM jobcli;
)
SELECT * FROM rownumbered_jobcli WHERE RN = 1;
```